# Creating Task Manager for Client Portal

Tags: templating, entries

**Background & Problem**

I've taken over our company website which was created using Craft. I've never worked with Craft and I'm beginning to like it, but the higher-ups want it done ASAP and I'm struggling understanding some things.

I've been tasked to add a page for our clients (AKA Client Portal). Each one of these pages will look and feel exactly the same with the exception of three areas (Discovery, Website, Assets) where the project manager will need to add tasks. These tasks will be a brief description and will be a link to some outside page (Dropbox or something else...).

**Progress**

I've created a Channel and called it Client Portal which works great! I can create a portal for each client and so far so good. The problem is I need to add these sections (not sure the proper Craft term) where they can add a Discovery task, Website task, Assets task. These are unique to the client, but will be styled exactly the same, but the content (text) will be different for each task/card. I'm not sure where to start with these sections (or whatever Craft calls them).

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I would create these sections?

I've created a JSFIDDLE to give someone a visual on what I'm trying to achieve.

https://jsfiddle.net/9goqgabp/

Comment: Do tasks need to be 'checked off' by the client?

Comment: The tasks are a pane with a title and a description that will have a link associated with it. The user will click on the pane and it will navigate them to whatever link. My goal is to give the Project Manager the ability to, once everything is created by me, login into Craft and simply add as many tasks for that client as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a "Matrix Block" and make 3 type of blocks in there:
Discovery task, Website task and Assets task. If you give these blocks the fields they should need they just add whatever block they need and fill it in the way they like. You can loop over these blocks so they get displayed.

They can be filled in differently for every "Client Portal"

You can find more info about matrix blocks here:
https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields

The Craft CMS Documentation is really good especially if you are just starting its really helpfull as it got all the basics and even more you need to build a website with Craft.

There is also a "Craft CMS Slack" where alot of developers discuss craft and ask questions daily so you can have a more direct explanation and probably a faster response.

https://craftcms.com/community#slack

Comment: I'll be sure to read up on Matrix's, sounds like what I need. Quick question, will using a matrix allow me/user to add multiples for each matrix I create? For example, if I create a Discovery Tasks matrix will I have the ability to add multiple tasks? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yes you can. You can just keep adding them and make them as complicated as you want. The user can fill them in on the edit page so just give enough options on them and think about variations in the options. I'd rather have 3 block types with a lot of options then 50 blocks with 3 options if you put it like that. It's fun to play around with and in the end very usefull too. Let me know if you need any more info or if you need more help then the docs provide.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it was perfect! Thank you so much for your help. I'm loving Craft and this community is really helpful!